# I cant use 3D painting in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I try to use Photoshop 3D function, but I fail.
I import a simple cube.obj file, but when I try to paint to it, whatever I draw to front side, it will be added on all other 5 sides too. How can I use this 3d paint feature if I wanna paint all sides differently?
Thanks,
Mue114

Answer (score 1):

You need a different cube! What you have is a cube that repears the UV coordinates on all sides. What you need is a model that does not repeat the UV coordinates. Since ohotoshop can not do anything about the model you need to redo the model in a 3D editor.